# PHP - Redirect After File is Uploaded to Server

Tags: php, redirect, upload

I have been looking around for a solution to this problem, and thus haven't found one. I'm hoping someone will be able to help me out with this problem.

I have this PHP script that gets the posted file, uploads, renames, and moves into a directory:

```
<?php

    $fileName   = $_POST['fileName'];

    if (!$fileName) $fileName = $distFile.rand(1,999)."-".basename($_COOKIE["email"]);
    $distFile   = dirname(__FILE__).'/audio/'.$fileName.'.wav';
    $error      = 'N';
    $message    = 'Your song was uploaded!';

    if (!isset($_FILES['wav']) || $_FILES['wav']['error'] > 0) {
        $error = 'Y';
        $message = 'Error while uploading. Error code: '.$_FILES['wav']['error'];
    } else {

        $res = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES['wav']['tmp_name'], $distFile);

        if (!$res) {
            $error = 'Y';
            $message = 'Unable to create the file.';
        }
    }

    echo '
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <response>
            <error value="'.$error.'" />
            <message>'.htmlspecialchars($message).'</message>
        </response>
    ';

?>
```

That all works fine, however whenever I try to implement a header redirect (like so):

```
<?php

    $fileName   = $_POST['fileName'];

    if (!$fileName) $fileName = $distFile.rand(1,999)."-".basename($_COOKIE["email"]);
    $distFile   = dirname(__FILE__).'/audio/'.$fileName.'.wav';
    $error      = 'N';
    $message    = 'Your song was uploaded!';
    if($filename) {
        header('Location: http://google.co.uk');
    }
```

I am unable to refresh the page. I must point out that this script is located in a different file than the page I am trying to reload. This script is located in the file `saveWav.php` and I am trying to reload `index.php`.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  What heppens when you remove the if condition around the redirect?

Comment: @ user20232359723568423357842364 I'm not getting any errors, and nothing happens when the if statement is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want you to replace your code to this

```
$fileName   = $_POST['fileName'];

if (!$fileName) 
{
    $fileName = $distFile.rand(1,999)."-".basename($_COOKIE["email"]);
    $distFile   = dirname(__FILE__).'/audio/'.$fileName.'.wav';
    $error      = 'N';
    $message    = 'Your song was uploaded!';
}
else
{
    header('Location: http://google.co.uk');
}
```

Comment: I've tried to implement this, no errors occur and the file uploads as I wanted, however the page index.php does not redirect.

Comment: then there might be a problem as i think that you may be providing wrong address for your index.php file. You need to confirm about the address of your index.php file.